# Use mouse on second screen

Tags: settings, android-11, mouse

I am toying with making a multi-screen Android 11 device. I managed to start a different app on each screen, using `am start -n <activity name> --display <display id>`. Also, I found a launcher, which is capable of starting apps on a screen of my choice.

But only one of the screens is a touch screen, and I am trying to use a mouse for the other (or preferably both) screens. Sadly, the mouse is limited to the first screen, which is also the touch screen. So I have two input devices on the first screen, and none on the second one.

How do I assign the mouse to the second screen? Is there any way to use the mouse on both screens?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial-and-error, the following worked for me on Android 13 on FairPhone 4:

1. put device in landscape mode
2. open list of recently opened apps
3. open window options of any app
4. select `Split window to right`

The window disappeared, but my USB mouse was moved to the secondary screen with Desktop mode.